# springSecurityService.encodePassword for Spring Boot only

Tags: spring-boot, security, grails, encoding

I have a legacy app made in grails which uses ***springSecurityService.encodePassword*** to generate user password. It's stored in database like this:

```
{bcrypt}$2a$04$hO0LTu6a54t41bVpxTfPCe0837vYQbA4dZ3HSTlpMEppoB9kmsz0y
```

On my new app made in Spring Boot only, I'm using ***BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password)***

I read that by default grails also uses bcrypt encode. but with spring-boot the password is stored like this:

```
$2a$10$zHHRMpHWoP6KByWkmgQWqeKN0k.mWE5uD3Fg0Fb92S5eNKaPS5puK
```

It looks like it's the same encoding but even manually entering the prefix *{bcrypt}* I can't access the legacy app and also removing it, legacy users can't access the new app.

How can I generate a spring password with the same encoding as *springSecurityService.encodePassword*?

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't match"? Are you expecting both hash codes to be same? or when you use match method, raw password and encoded one is not matching? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: @Luccas It would be helpful if you updated the question to clarify what it is you are looking for an answer to.  It isn't clear if you are trying to confirm that by default the Grails plugin uses bcrypt, if you are asking why the stored values are different, or something else.

Comment: updated as requested